# Check and replace text in a string from a text file

Tags: php

I have this script that reads the last 100 lines from a text file, I explode out each line into 3 chunks were separated by a space. The third chunk of data I want to check to see if it contains a word or phrase from one of the lines in another text file `filters.txt`. If a match is found, then I want to replace that word or phrase with some formatting so it stands out. Below is what I have but it does not work, the code that checks against the filters has no effect.

Can anyone please show me how I should do this.

Thanks in advance.

Here is a line from sample.log...

12:12:46 18-10-18 #:10656200,1A,29D09 ,RTC NOT ALERT , ,CHEMIST WAREHOUSE , , ,910 David Low Way ,MARCOOLA ,S59K7 , , ,

In the filters.txt file will be lines such as...

RTC

RTC INJURIES

RTC NOT ALERT

RTC HIGH MECH

In above exmaple when I print out the data I want the 'RTC NOT ALERT' to be highlighted so it stands out. So in brief, for every line in sample.log I want to see if any of the filters appear in it, if so I want it to be highlighted on output. I do this by changing the font styling with css.

```
<?php


// OPEN LOG FILE FOR READING
$file = array_reverse( file( 'sample.log' ));

// OPEN FILTERS LIST
$filters = file( 'filters.txt' );


// START MAIN LOOP (SHOWS LAST X LINES FROM TEXT FILE)

$limit = 100;
for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++ ){
$data = explode(' ', $file[$i],3);



// CHECK FOR FILTERS AND HIGHLIGHT IF MATCHED

foreach ( $filters as $filter ){
if (strpos($data[2], $filter) !== false) {
$data[2] = str_replace($filter,"<font 
class=\"highlight\">$filter</font>",$data[2]);
    }
}


// PRINT LIST

print "

<div class=\"code1a\">
<font class=\"time\">$data[0] $data[1]</font><br>
$data[2]
</div>

";


}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you didn't give any example from sample.log and filters.txt, I think you need to trim each $filter because of line-break.

Try:

```
<?php
// OPEN LOG FILE FOR READING
$file = array_reverse( file( 'sample.log' ) );

// OPEN FILTERS LIST
$filters = file( 'filters.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );

// START MAIN LOOP (SHOWS LAST X LINES FROM TEXT FILE)
$limit = 100;

// BECAUSE $file STARTS WITH 0
$limit -= 1;

foreach ( $file as $line => $line_content ) {
    if ( $line == $limit ) {
        break;
    }

    $data       = explode( ' ', $line_content, 3 );
    $highlight  = $data[ 2 ];

    // CHECK FOR FILTERS AND HIGHLIGHT IF MATCHED
    foreach ( $filters as $filter ) {
        if ( strpos( $highlight, ',' . $filter . ' ,'  ) !== false ) {
            $highlight = str_replace( $filter, '<font class="highlight">' . $filter . '</font>', $highlight );
        }
    }

    // PRINT LIST
    echo '<div class="code1a">';
    echo '<font class="time">', $data[ 0 ], ' ', $data[ 1 ], '</font>';
    echo '<br />';
    echo $highlight;
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: thanks Zavarock, I will try your suggestion soon. Regards

Comment: no problems bro. i edited my answer, let me know if it works.

Comment: _“I think you need to trim each $filter because of line-break”_ - the alternative to that would be to simply read the manual for `file` …

Comment: You're perfectly right. To be honest, I never used this function, just tested, we live and learn, but no excuses. I edited again and improved it a little.

Comment: Works perfect, thanks again for your help, I learnt something.